# Mathematica Plot failed to visualize very acute changes

Tags: plotting, visualization

I am plotting a variable evolution with the results calculated by NDSolve. It reduced from 1.0 to 0.9 in the first 0.0001 seconds, while I want to plot this variable from 0 to 800 seconds. However, the acute reduction can't be fully visualized. The part from 1.0 to 0.95 seems missed. As shown in the attached figure. 
However, if zoom in, the acute change can be captured, as it is shown in the Epilog.

Could anyone help with this issue? Thanks.

Here is my command to plot:

```
p1 = Plot[{Evaluate[{n0N[t] + 1.0}] /. s(*,n0L*)}, {t, tstart1,tend1},
Frame -> True,FrameLabel -> {"t[s]", "n[t]"},PlotRange -> {0.7, 1.0},
ImagePadding -> All, ImageSize -> Full,LabelStyle -> 40, AspectRatio -> iar, 
PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.001],
Epilog -> {Arrow[{{500, 0.85}, {5, 0.975}}],
Inset[Plot[{Evaluate[{n0N[t] + 1.0}] /. s(*,n0L*)}, {t, 0, 0.0001}, 
PlotRange -> {0.7, 1.0},PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[2]} ,
BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> ifs*0.9}, ImageSize -> isize/3.5,Background -> White], {600, 0.85}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding the option PlotPoints -> 100 to your Plot command.

Comment: Thanks, SHuisman, this option does work! And I have to set it up to 1000 to capture the evolution.